# CSS Animation ( @keyframes ) is heating up CPU

Tags: css, performance, animation

I have a simple CSS animation as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/628uzdfn/

It simply has one animation `@keyframes` which is causing the problem ( when I remove animation, it doesn't heat up CPU )( [*stylus syntax*](http://stylus-lang.com/) ):

```
@keyframes moving

    from
        transform translateX( 0 ) translateZ( 0 )

    to
        transform translateX( -15% ) translateZ( 0 )
```

The problem is if you let this page live for more than 10 seconds, you're going to feel the warmth under your laptop. If you leave it for more than 30 seconds, it will sound like a tractor!

I've already read performance-related stuff on [html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) so I tried to limit my animating properties to only `transform` even tried to put `translateZ( 0 )` to ask for help from GPU, but it just doesn't change a thing.

You can see my performance profiling here as well:

[image: Performance profile on FireFox]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

What should I do to improve my animation in terms of its performance?

*Update*: Forgot to mention this animation is `infinite` so it can be the problem, but why is it happening? I've already seen many infinite CSS-animations which didn't make a performance issue. It should be something else causing the problem.

Comment: Can you try to add css property `will-change: transform` on element you're applying animation on and check if it helps?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik It will be my pleasure if you check my jsFiddle, I already set that, but nothing happened.

Comment: It seems to be working well in Chrome, are you using a different browser?

Comment: @Joru I'm trying to make an add-on for FireFox, so yeah, I'm using FireFox Quantum 63.0.3 and tested on chrome too, it had the same problem for me. You definitely have a better config laptop than me, but would you please look at the source and tell me if there's anything wrong?

Comment: For me it doesn't seem to use any resources at all so I doubt that it's the hardware that's making the difference. Do you have up-to-date graphics drivers and OS?

Comment: @Joru I've not updated to the macOS Mojave and that shouldn't be the problem. Because then what if someone doesn't update to the latest version of macOS? Should experience this nightmare as well? But I'm not sure about my graphics driver, I can run Hearthstone and Dota 2 on my laptop, so I've doubt if the driver has any problems.

Comment: @mrReiha, since you're using `translateX`, you don't need `translateZ(0)` as you're already using `3d`. Also, `will-change` won't help as the animation is too simple to optimize, but using `will-change` will eat some memory and may worsen the performance. BTW, you might make the same [animation](https://jsfiddle.net/63jk28u9/) with less code and more flexibility.

Comment: @KoshVery That was an interesting solution, thanks for details you've provided. But it will go crazy after 30 seconds just like my own example! And I'm desperately don't know what's going on. That's the most important thing for me, to figure out what's exactly happening.

Comment: @mrReiha, the heating problem seems to be specific to your computer. I could not reproduce it even opening 10 windows simultaneously. I'd suggest you to check if your browser use hardware acceleration.

Comment: @KoshVery well, I've double checked that at the performance section in preferences, and yeah that was checked there to use hardware acceleration. I would love to ask you to do a favor for me, open [this link](http://deyh.im/mousavi/) up and you can see two different types of animations at the first section, hovering sole logo at the top, and infinite CSS animation on the scroll-down part at the bottom of the section. but none of them making my CPU to sound like when I open these examples. Really weird.

Comment: What computer is this?

Comment: @arman311 MacBook Pro 2015. macOS Sierra ( 10.12.6 )

Comment: @mrReiha Ah. Any idea what CPU is in it?

Comment: @arman311 Yeap, 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5.

Comment: Ah. Then I do not know the answer. I was thinking about a similar problem I had that was caused by an Intel Core M, but an i5 is sufficient.1

Comment: I can't reproduce the performance issues on Firefox Linux, but I suggest to use translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) since it will use GPU for the animation http://jsfiddle.net/umcp8w5x/

Comment: @DanielDoblado Yeah I've heard that multiple times which the problem is happening only on my device, but still happening. I'm getting really annoyed by this!
but about the `translate3d()` option you've suggested, there's a `translateZ()` already there, so I think `translate3d()` won't change anything.

Comment: Does it get better if you add `overflow: hidden` to `.container`? The street seems to overflow but you cannot see it because the page and blocks are both white.

Comment: @SalmanA Maybe I forgot to put `overflow: hidden` on example, don't remember. but the actual design has `overflow: hidden` indeed; still problem occurs.

Comment: Does this help? https://jsfiddle.net/628uzdfn/2/ I changed the animation from translate to margin

Comment: @HerrSerker That definitely doesn't help, it will just add a painful paint to each frame of animation

Comment: @mrReiha Then I can't help. From a performance point-of-view your original animation shouldn't have any issues. The animation is just too basic and small. You shouldn't have the heating issues in the first place.

Comment: @HerrSerker Yeah, I know, but it's happening and it's *probably* not my fault.

Comment: @mrReiha I'm not talking about who to blame. I wanted to solve an issue that O don't even have. Alas it is *very* difficult for us to help if the original issue is not reproducable on other people's equipment. What you might want to think about: Your second to last comment could be considered rude. I'm not offended personally, but I might lose motivation to help you, as others might as well.

Comment: @HerrSerker It just didn't have anything to you. I was saying that it's really hard for me to experience something on my well-prepared device that others doesn't can even see. and it was more of a *joke*. didn't mean to hurt you at all, sorry btw.

Comment: @mrReiha Nobody was harmed. But you know, written jokes on the internet are risky.

Comment: @HerrSerker Honey, u have serious problems <3

Comment: Hey... have you managed to solve your issue? I am facing the same thing with my MBP 2017

Comment: @Alioshr I still have the same problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: I have read some articles in medium about this and it seems that infinite animations boil up notebooks. Take a look at this one https://medium.com/better-programming/do-not-burn-you-cpu-working-with-css-animations-e4d19069fb0f

Comment: It seems that we should avoid animations in CSS, especially the infinite ones. I had a chevron pointing down from my homepage front banner, moving infinitely, and I had the CPU up to 90% while doing other stuff on the page development while the animation ran. I have given up the infinite deal and made it run just 4 times upon rendering the page,

Comment: Other infinite animations you may have could be replaced by GIFs, for example, which will run much much much leaner

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what wrong with your computer but in my computer, CPU is not a big problem. Testing in Chrome 66.0, Ubuntu 18.04.
 Your animation is simple but it can be optimized 2x (CPU) better just by changing `translateX( -15% )` to `translateX( -108px )`. `108px` equal `15%` width of your element but it is in fixed pixcel. Browser do not need to re-caculate the value each frame of animation. So it will definitely use less CPU. Here is the result of my CPU before and after optimizing
Before
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: Actually, that was a good point to consider, but that's not possible. since the other design decisions were made, that's impossible to use pixel-based units there. my `.street` element will have various sizes. fixed *600px* in fiddle is just for creating the example.

Comment: @mrReiha I think that's all i can do with your animation. It is really a simple animation

Comment: That was a really good point of view man, appreciated. voted up. but just couldn't help me fixing my problem :(

Answer (score 4):

There's no way for me to test this, but I'm giving it a shot.

My initial thoughts on why this might be happening after you've already made the correct css GPU enhancements is from the `%`'s and `float`'s and the amount of `.block`'s your animating (just some wild guesses).

I made the changes and recreated the `.block`'s with a `repeating-linear-gradient` with a few other changes.

https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/JwbpPz

```css
@keyframes moving {
 from  { transform: translateX(-50px) translateZ(0); }
 to   { transform: translateX(-150px) translateZ(0); }    
}

.container {
 width: 600px;
 height: 100px;
}

.street {
 background: #333;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
 animation:  moving 1.5s linear infinite;
 will-change: transform;
 display: block;
 width: 200%; height: 6px;
 transform: translateX(-50px);
   background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent, transparent 50px, white 50px, white 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="street">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate all the efforts community is giving for my problem. about your provided answer, if I'm not mistaken, @kosh already used this specific technique ( it's interesting anyway). I'm working on something else right now, but I will test your pen ASAP. thanks <3

Comment: ahh I just saw his fiddle.

Comment: I've never heard of `float` to be heavy and this is really weird! but all of those enhancements you've mentioned ( removing `.block` elements and `float`s ) it looks like to behave smoother. CPU is gonna go hot again, but maybe more 20 seconds need to happen ( first example went crazy after 30 seconds, and your example needs 50 - 60 seconds for that case ). voted up, but I still there's no explanation about what's exactly happening ( I think no one would be able to do so : )))) ) so, I can't accept as best answer :(